# What is wrong with my website's scroll bars?

Tags: html, scroll, dreamweaver

I have made a website, using HTML and Dreamweaver.

The thing is, when i get to the bottom of the page, it carries on scrolling, and I can't scroll back up.

There also is this annoying horizontal scroll, that I want to remove.

The website is: www.itsol.ml - if you'd like to see for yourself!

Comment: place the code you've tried in the question please!

Comment: The horizontal scrolling is coming from your `#about` div, the one with the notebook image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `#testimonials` div is not correctly closed. Add another `</div>` at your comment `<!-- TESTIMONIAL SECTIONHEAD END -->`. This should fix the vertical scroll problem. It will also fix the layout at the bottom.

As for the vertical scrolling: you can put another div around your `#about` one with `overflow: hidden`.

```
<div style="overflow: hidden">
    <div id="about">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the same issue for the vertical scroll.

As for the horizontal scroll bar, to remove it completely just remove the specific child in this div (the div in the next part):

```
<div id="ascrail2000-hr">
```

If you want to fix its length instead, you will have to fix the bunch of code that gives it a fixed width:

```
<div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; height: 5px; background-color: rgb(234, 147, 18); border: medium none; background-clip: padding-box; border-radius: 10px; left: 0px; width: 1236px;">
```

Comment: I believe this would only remove the custom scrollbar but the issue with the horizontal scrolling itself would persist. Also I guess this div is generated by the scroll plugin.

Comment: On my browser there was no horizontal scrolling so I assumed he was referring to the scroll bar, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

remove `overflow:hidden` from html head style attribute and css preloader.css line 2